# Best solution to switch staging Table to main Table, avoid access when main table is empty

Tags: sql-server

I have a large table (10 million rows) on SQLServer 2014 which is rebuilt regularly by a procedure which writes the data in a staging table, then switches the data into the production table. 
Currently I do TRUNCATE the Main table then INSERT into it from the Staging table.

```
-- Empty Main table
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[MainTable];

-- Switch data from Staging table into Main table
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MainTable] SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MainTableStaging];
```

This truncate-insert process takes approx. 2 seconds. 
Very important I must make sure nobody can read the main table while it is empty.

First question:
Can I 'LOCK' the Main table between the TRUNCATE TABLE and the INSERT to avoid any read returning empty records ?  Using TABLOCKX ? Any other way ?

Second question:
What would be the pro/cons of using ALTER TABLE instead of INSERT ?

```
-- Empty Main table
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[MainTable];

-- Empty Main table
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MainTableStaging] SWITCH TO [dbo].[MainTable];
```

Comment: I have to run so not enough time for a thorough answer. Wrap the 2 statements in a transaction. `SWITCH` will be much faster than `INSERT...SELECT`.

Comment: BTW I just found the answer to my 2nd question here            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348523/how-does-alter-table-switch-works-on-sql-server